# Excel - Reference cell in other sheet

Tags: excel-2010

I am trying to get the value of a cell in another sheet based on the value of 'A4'

Thus: In sheet1, the value of A4 = JOHN DOE and i'm trying to ref cell B14 from another sheet called 'JOHN DOE' , but the names in column A on sheet1 will change, so im look for a way to use the value of 'A4' as the sheet name to reference.
I've looked at =INDIRECT but cant get it to work. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the cells with the next formula:

SheetName!CellAddress (Precede the cell address with the worksheet name, and follow it with an exclamation point).

Example:

```
  =Sheet3!A4
```

if the sheet has spaces in the name must be enclosed in single quotes.

Example:

```
  ='Sheet with spaces'!A4
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You missed the point of the post - the sheet name needs to be equal to the value of cell A4. So based on your example: ='Value of cell A4'!B14 ... but thats what i cant figure out

Comment: Got it in the end. From sheet1, to reference cell B14 on another sheet with the same name as the value of cell A4 (on sheet1) use: 

    =SUM(INDIRECT("'"&A4&"'!B14"))